# The antagonist in the no miracle argument

Tags: scientific-realism, hilary-putnam

We have from Putnam’s Mathematics, Matter and Method:
“The positive argument for realism is that it is the only philosophy that doesn’t make the success of science a miracle”

-and from Stanford Encyclopedia (Scientific Realism):

For example, van Fraassen /…/suggests that successful theories are analogous to well-adapted organisms—since only successful theories (organisms) survive, it is hardly surprising that our theories are successful, and therefore, there is no demand here for an explanation of success.
It seems that both sides argue on very general term without identifying a group of people (or traditions) with faulty reasoning without more details about the errors of their ways.

As requested, I try to find a solution but I don't really come up with much. I consider a few scenarios in my search for gestalt here:

**Advances at a zombie university**

If we consider a university with fumbling scientists almost like zombies, it would be a miracle if they made important scientific discoveries, but this is clearly not what Putnam meant.

**Work under pressure**

Science made in an authoritarian regime like a religious sect or during Stalin’s Lysenko affair.
According to one account, “the August 1948 session of the Agricultural Academy at which Lysenko triumphantly presented his report, “On the Situation in Soviet Biology,” was one of five such occasions in the late Stalin period when scientific disputes were settled by party intervention. In this case there was a triumphant announcement of scientific situation of Soviet Biology.

In  a much weaker version, we might include Kuhn’s observation that while we don’t have Stalin’s eyes on us, we might still work under the influence of a theoretical Überbau, which might prevent us from good science and therefore approach paradigm changes as either nonsense or miracles.
I don’t really think this was what Putnam meant.

**Introduction of relativity**

I consider the small and careful steps, carried out before 1900 by Lorentz–FitzGerald, and I wonder if such smaller steps would be nearer van Fraassen’s adaptive formula for knowledge growth.
I also consider the enormous international praise of Einstein later, where the theory is considered quite remarkable if not a miracle.

All this make me wonder about the no miracle argument, and I wonder if it was made more as a praise made in passing, rather than a fundamental proposal.

I have only seen a few summaries. I realize there might be much more in the full text of the authors.

Comment: Did you read the essay? Please state your point as an explicit question. - "I realize ...": Do you mean: "I expect ..."? - Which "authors" (plural) of which works do you mean?

Comment: Re Putnam: what about Pragmatism?

Comment: the no miracles argument can be straightfowardly characterised as: *novel* empirical predictions of science would be *like* a miracle without realism.

Comment: @Jo Wehler I have only read summaries from Wikipedia etc. not the essays. I have read one essay about von Frassen's point of view. I don't mean "expect" because I don't know what to expect, and the authors are Putnam and von Fraassen. The question may be phrased better as "what are the antagonists..."

Comment: @prof_ghost I agree with your comment but I also try to find out whether Putnam's view is a critical point in a discussion between different antagonistic viewpoints (wondering what these might be), or if he views the statement in my quote above as an expression that he expect everyone to accept.  I am therefore looking into ALLEGRANZA's comment.